# Simpliest component with Hooks fails Jest test with error "Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component."

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I am trying to write tests for my application using Jest, but I am facing the same issue for every functional component that uses React Hooks.

This is my `package.json` file, but I can't see what might be wrong with it.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "automock": false,
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupJest.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-sms": "^5.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.185.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.7.5",
    "react-native-spacer": "^1.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "util": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "jest-expo": "^33.0.2",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AppText from '../AppText/AppText';

const CommonErrorModal = (props) => {
  const {
    errorDetails
  } = props;
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      {
        showDetails
          ? <AppText>{errorDetails}</AppText>
          : <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowDetails(true)} />
      }
    </View>
  );
};

export default CommonErrorModal;
```

and here is the test:

```
test('renders correctly CommonErrorModal', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<CommonErrorModal />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Could anybody provide my info what should I add to my project to make this work?

EDIT

Full error from console:

```
  console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8218
    The above error occurred in the <CommonErrorModal> component:
        in CommonErrorModal

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit fb.me/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

 FAIL  src/components/common/__tests__/Common-components-test.js
  ✓ renders correctly ActionBarButton (116ms)
  ✓ renders correctly AppText (1ms)
  ✓ renders correctly Button (1ms)
  ✓ renders correctly CategorySelector (57ms)
  ✕ renders correctly CommonErrorModal (9ms)
  ✓ renders correctly ConfirmModal (10ms)
  ✓ renders correctly DropdownSelect (2ms)
  ✓ renders correctly FontIcon
  ✓ renders correctly HorizontalSeparator (1ms)
  ✓ renders correctly InfoModal (2ms)
  ✓ renders correctly Input (16ms)
  ✓ renders correctly LoadingIndicator (4ms)
  ✓ renders correctly LocationPicker (9ms)
  ✓ renders correctly MapPicker (3ms)
  ✓ renders correctly SectionHeader (2ms)
  ✓ renders correctly SquareTile
  ✓ renders correctly StudentsPicker (3ms)
  ✓ renders correctly TextInCircle (1ms)
  ✓ renders correctly TimePicker (56ms)

  ● renders correctly CommonErrorModal

    Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. (fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call)

       7 |     errorDetails
       8 |   } = props;
    >  9 |   const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);
         |                                         ^
      10 | 
      11 |   return (
      12 |     <View>

      at invariant (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:88:15)
      at resolveDispatcher (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1436:28)
      at useState (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1461:20)
      at CommonErrorModal (src/components/common/CommonErrorModal/CommonErrorModal.js:9:41)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7016:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7521:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10358:12)
      at workLoop (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10390:24)
      at renderRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10476:7)
      at performWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11342:7)
```

Comment: Without test your application is running fine? Or its giving same error with or without test?

Comment: Post your complete error here.

Comment: Edited original question with full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it :) Of course it was my mistake because I forgot to upgrade `react-test-renderer` to match the Expo React version (16.8.3).

Comment: It is the smartest thing to do right away

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to `test`, but if you're trying to make sure that the `UI` is consistent when you're working with a `global` style potentially shared between `components`, use it this way.

```js
describe('< CommonErrorModal />', () => {
  it('renders correctly CommonErrorModal', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(< CommonErrorModal />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: @KamilG If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer for my question. I does not matter what I am trying to test because every test with component that uses React Hooks fails with this message.